# Sum or Product with Exclusions

Tags: functions, summation

Is there a built-in feature for handling things like:

$$\sum_{\substack{i=0\\i\ne j}}^n\frac{a-a_i}{a_i-a_j}$$
and
$$\prod_{\substack{i=0\\i\ne j}}^n\frac{a-a_i}{a_i-a_j}$$

or should I work out some sort of `Do` statement?

Comment: Either of `If[]` or `Boole[]` is useful.

Comment: @J.M. Yes, I ended up using `Product[If[k != j, (x - l[[j]])/(l[[k]] - l[[j]]), 1], {j, 1, 
  Length[l]}]`, just wondering if there was something built in to take care of things like this. Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Product.html#52817570), BTW?

Comment: @J.M. I had not - that's perfect, care to make it an answer?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The documentation for `Product[]` gives [a nice example](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Product.html#52817570) that you can adapt to your needs:

```
With[{j = 2, n = 6},
     Sum[(a - Subscript[a, i])/(Subscript[a, i] - Subscript[a, j]),
         {i, Complement[Range[0, n], {j}]}]]

(a - Subscript[a, 0])/(Subscript[a, 0] - Subscript[a, 2]) +
(a - Subscript[a, 1])/(Subscript[a, 1] - Subscript[a, 2]) +
(a - Subscript[a, 3])/(-Subscript[a, 2] + Subscript[a, 3]) +
(a - Subscript[a, 4])/(-Subscript[a, 2] + Subscript[a, 4]) +
(a - Subscript[a, 5])/(-Subscript[a, 2] + Subscript[a, 5]) +
(a - Subscript[a, 6])/(-Subscript[a, 2] + Subscript[a, 6])
```

and similarly for `Product[]`. Alternatively, you can do

```
With[{j = 2, n = 6},
     Sum[(a - Subscript[a, i])/(Subscript[a, i] - Subscript[a, j]),
         {i, DeleteCases[Range[0, n], j]}]]
```

Answer (score 9):

J. M.'s method is appropriate for sums (and products) that will be computed iteratively.
It is however quite inappropriate for sums that can be computed symbolically.

You could use `Piecewise` in the latter case.  Here is an illustration using a very simple function:

```
Sum[5 i, {i, Range[1*^7] ~Delete~ 777}] // Timing
```

> {2.543, 250000024996115}

```
Sum[Piecewise[{{0, i == 777}}, 5 i], {i, x}] /. x -> 1*^7 // Timing
```

> {0.047, 250000024996115}

The output of the symbolic sum is itself a `Piecewise` function:

```
Sum[Piecewise[{{0, i == 777}}, 5 i], {i, x}]
```

> ```
> Piecewise[{{5, x == 1}, {(5*x*(1 + x))/2, 1 < x < 777] || x < 1}}, (5*(-1554 + x + x^2))/2]
> ```

`Boole` often performs poorly with the default Method:

```
Sum[Boole[i != 777] 5 i, {i, x}] /. x -> 1*^7 // Timing
```

> {11.403, 250000024996115}

(Symbol `x` above should be `\[FormalX]` for safety, but I kept the simple form for brevity.)

One can also compute infinite sums in this fashion, e.g.:

```
Sum[
  Piecewise[{{0, i == 3 || i == 5 || i == 7}}, 1/i^6],
  {i, ∞}
]
```

> ```
> (-1935422371 + 1418090625 π^6)/1340095640625
> ```

It may be simpler to compute two sums and subtract when possible:

```
Sum[1/i^6, {i, ∞}] - Sum[1/i^6, {i, {3, 5, 7}}]
```

---

Beware when using conditions that evaluate on non-numeric arguments (e.g. `PrimeQ`):

```
Sum[Piecewise[{{0, PrimeQ[i]}}, i], {i, x}]
```

> ```
> 1/2 x (1 + x)   (* clearly incorrect *)
> ```

Comment: @MrWizard: Did you inform Wolfram about this error? It is still there in v10.

Comment: @Jinxed No, I did not report the error.  It would be nice if a warning was given but IMHO it belongs to a class of problems where user intelligence is necessary.  I mean by that that there are many things *Mathematica* fails to "think through" for you.  Such things are not really bugs but limitations, and while it would be nice to see those limitations pushed back (prioritized over social networking functions \*cough\*) the system still has ample value as it is if one is willing to work with it. (continued)

Comment: In this case it seems reasonable to conclude that *Mathematica* will not be able to give a closed form for the sum of prime numbers, or their complement, so it would be best not to set it up to fail.  If we use `f[i_Integer] := Piecewise[{{0, PrimeQ[i]}}, i]; 
Sum[f[i], {i, x}]` it returns unevaluated.  If we use use `Sum[f[i], {i, 1*^6}]` it evaluates numerically and returns `462450097977`.  However I encourage you to report this issue yourself as these reports may help Wolfram Research see that such things are important to its users and improve these core and mathematical functions.

Comment: @MrWizard: I will do that, since what I expect from *Mathematica* is not necessarily a result for everything, but if a result is produced, it shall be correct. I'd rather live with an unevaluated "results" than a wrong one.