# Representation of product with exclusions

Tags: functions, output-formatting

Is there a nice way to define output formatting for my expression, a product from `n = k` to `j` with `n ≠ m`? I would like to use something like this here (however *Mathematica* doesn't evaluate it):

$$\prod _{n=k,n\neq m}^j \frac{\lambda _n}{\lambda _n-\lambda _m}$$

My work around at the moment is: (adopted from [Sum or Product with Exclusions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9288/sum-or-product-with-exclusions))

$$\prod _n^{\text{DeleteCases[Range[k, j], m]}} \frac{\lambda _n}{\lambda _n-\lambda _m}$$

Answer (score 8):

To make it possible to enter the expression the way you want, and also display it that way, I'll create an `InputAlias` for it similar to the already existing shortcut <kbd>esc</kbd>`prodt`<kbd>esc</kbd>. Then I also define the format for `TraditionalForm` output to look the way you enter it.

The first step is to define your choice of modified product function, called `restrictedProduct` here. I decided to go with the approach based on `Piecewise` in which factors for which the added condition is violated are replaced by `1`. Before implementing the actual product, I also prevent it from evaluating its arguments and to work with local variables as `Product` does:

```
SetAttributes[restrictedProduct, HoldAll]
SyntaxInformation[
   restrictedProduct] = {"LocalVariables" -> {"Product", {2, 2}}, 
   "ArgumentsPattern" -> {_, _, _}};

restrictedProduct[f_, range_, condition_] := 
 Product[Piecewise[{{f, condition}, {1, True}}], range]

restrictedProduct /: 
 MakeBoxes[restrictedProduct[f_, {i_, i0_, i1_}, condition_], 
  TraditionalForm] :=
 TemplateBox[{ToBoxes[i], ToBoxes[i0], RowBox[{ToBoxes[condition]}], 
   ToBoxes[i1], ToBoxes[f]},
    "conditionalProduct",
    DisplayFunction :> (RowBox[{
            UnderoverscriptBox["\[Product]", 
              GridBox[{{
                    RowBox[{#, "=", #2}]}, {#3}}], #4], #5}] & ),
    InterpretationFunction :> (RowBox[{"restrictedProduct", "[", 
            RowBox[{#5, ",", "{", #, ",", #2, ",", #4, "}", ",", #3}], 
            "]"}] & )]
```

The last definition is the output format in `TraditionalForm` - it contains a `TemplateBox` which allows it to become an editable expression that can be executed after you copy such output into a new input cell. The `DisplayFunction` and `InterpretationFunction` options are crucial to associate the two-dimensional box form with the input arguments of the function `restrictedProduct`.

Now I use the same association in defining the input alias that can be set for the current notebook as follows:

```
aliases = Options[EvaluationNotebook[], InputAliases];
newAliases = 
  Join[InputAliases /. 
    aliases, {"condProd" -> 
     TemplateBox[{"\[SelectionPlaceholder]", "\[Placeholder]", 
       "\[Placeholder]", "\[Placeholder]", "\[Placeholder]"}, 
      "conditionalProduct", DisplayFunction :> 
       (RowBox[{
           UnderoverscriptBox["\[Product]", 
            GridBox[{{RowBox[{#1, "=", #2}]}, {#3}}], #4], #5}] &),
      InterpretationFunction :> (RowBox[{"restrictedProduct", "[", 
           RowBox[{#5, ",", "{", #1, ",", #2, ",", #4, "}", ",", #3}],
            "]"}] &)
      ]}];
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], InputAliases -> newAliases];
```

Now we can start using this. In a new input cell, type

> <kbd>esc</kbd>`condProd`<kbd>esc</kbd>

[image: template]

In the template that appears, enter the desired limits, and note that the **condition** is inserted in the bottom box.

[image: entries]

> `64`

Instead of evaluating the expression, you can now also display it in held form as follows:

[image: traditional]

> $$\prod_{\stackrel{i = 1}{i\ne 3}}^{10} i$$

You can then, if needed, copy and paste this output to get at first the unevaluated expression in `StandardForm`, which then can be evaluated too:

```
restrictedProduct[i, {i, 1, 10}, i != 3]
```

> `1209600`

Comment: Wow, I assumed I just missed a build-in capability of Mathematica, but it's quite a bit more difficult. Thank you very much indeed!