# Can I enter the traditional form for Binomial as input in an expression?

Tags: notebooks, formatting, traditional-form

Is there a way to enter the traditional form of a binomial coefficient, i.e. ${n \choose k}$ instead of `Binomial[n,k]`, like I would enter a radical sign $\sqrt{x}$ using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>2</kbd>?  I would like to enter it that way in a notebook, and see it in that form in the input as well as output equations, just like the radical.  I know that I can use `TraditionalForm` to convert it on output, but I don't need to do that to see radicals instead of `Sqrt`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could do it using the following (this is the first version of the answer; don't use it if you want the more complete solution below):

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[],InputAliases->{"bn"->
 FormBox[TemplateBox[{"\[SelectionPlaceholder]",
  "\[Placeholder]"},"Binomial"],InputForm]}]
```

Then enter <kbd>esc</kbd>bn<kbd>esc</kbd> to get a placeholder that you can tab through:

[image: pic]

Then enter the numbers and press shift-enter to evaluate.

**Edit**

To make the output appear formatted without invoking `TraditionalForm`, you'd have to define a wrapper function and its style. I'll set the keyboard shortcut in a way that doesn't erase previous definitions.

```
ClearAll[myBinomial]

appearance[x_, y_] := TemplateBox[{x, y}, "myBinomial",
  DisplayFunction :> (RowBox[{"(", "\[NoBreak]", 
       GridBox[{{#1}, {#2}}, RowSpacings -> 1, ColumnSpacings -> 1, 
        RowAlignments -> Baseline, ColumnAlignments -> Center], 
       "\[NoBreak]", ")"}] &), 
  InterpretationFunction :> (RowBox[{"myBinomial", "[", 
       RowBox[{#1, ",", #2}], "]"}] &)
  ]

myBinomial[n_?NumericQ, k_?NumericQ] := Binomial[n, k]

myBinomial /: MakeBoxes[myBinomial[n_, k_], StandardForm] := 
 appearance[ToBoxes[n], ToBoxes[k]]

SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
 InputAliases -> 
  DeleteDuplicates@
   Join[{"bn" -> 
      appearance["\[SelectionPlaceholder]", "\[Placeholder]"]}, 
    InputAliases /. 
      Quiet[Options[EvaluationNotebook[], InputAliases]] /. 
     InputAliases -> {}]
 ]
```

Now the template appears as before, but when the function arguments aren't numerical, it's also displayed in 2D form. One could add additional definitions to `myBinomial` depending on what cases you want the 2D display to apply to. Whenever there is *no* definition for `myBinomial`, it is left unevaluated and will be displayed in the formatted style.

**Update in response to comment:**

Similar templates can also be created for other two-dimensional symbols using other types of brackets. As an example, here are shortcuts for [`StirlingS1`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StirlingS1.html) and [`StirlingS2`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StirlingS2.html) that can be entered as <kbd>esc</kbd>s1<kbd>esc</kbd> and <kbd>esc</kbd>s2<kbd>esc</kbd>:

```
appearanceS1[x_, y_] := 
 TemplateBox[{x, y}, "myStirlingS1", 
  DisplayFunction :> (StyleBox[
      RowBox[{"[", "\[NoBreak]", 
        GridBox[{{#1}, {#2}}, RowSpacings -> 1, ColumnSpacings -> 1, 
         RowAlignments -> Baseline, ColumnAlignments -> Center], 
        "\[NoBreak]", "]"}], SpanMaxSize -> Infinity] &), 
  InterpretationFunction :> (RowBox[{"myStirlingS1", "[", 
       RowBox[{#1, ",", #2}], "]"}] &)]

myStirlingS1[n_?NumericQ, k_?NumericQ] := StirlingS1[n, k]

myStirlingS1 /: MakeBoxes[myStirlingS1[n_, k_], StandardForm] := 
 appearanceS1[ToBoxes[n], ToBoxes[k]]

appearanceS2[x_, y_] := 
 TemplateBox[{x, y}, "myStirlingS2", 
  DisplayFunction :> (StyleBox[
      RowBox[{"{", "\[NoBreak]", 
        GridBox[{{#1}, {#2}}, RowSpacings -> 1, ColumnSpacings -> 1, 
         RowAlignments -> Baseline, ColumnAlignments -> Center], 
        "\[NoBreak]", "}"}], SpanMaxSize -> Infinity] &), 
  InterpretationFunction :> (RowBox[{"myStirlingS2", "[", 
       RowBox[{#1, ",", #2}], "]"}] &)]

myStirlingS2[n_?NumericQ, k_?NumericQ] := StirlingS2[n, k]

myStirlingS2 /: MakeBoxes[myStirlingS2[n_, k_], StandardForm] := 
 appearanceS2[ToBoxes[n], ToBoxes[k]]

SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
 InputAliases -> 
  DeleteDuplicates@
   Join[{"s1" -> 
      appearanceS1["\[SelectionPlaceholder]", "\[Placeholder]"], 
     "s2" -> appearanceS2["\[SelectionPlaceholder]", 
       "\[Placeholder]"]}, 
    InputAliases /. 
      Quiet[Options[EvaluationNotebook[], InputAliases]] /. 
     InputAliases -> {}]
 ]
```

In these definitions, I added one additional ingredient: the square and curly brackets for these symbols are not automatically **extensible**, so they don't grow like the round brackets used in `Binomial`. To fix this, I added a `StyleBox` with option `SpanMaxSize -> Infinity`.

Also, the shortcuts are be appended to the `InputAliases` without erasing previous definitions. To make the shortcuts work, this step has to be done *after* defining the wrapper functions `appearance` and `appearanceS1/S2`.

With this, you can get output like this:

[image: s1]

for `StirlingS1` and

[image: s2]

for `StirlingS2`.

Comment: Awesome!  Though it comes out as `Binomial[n,k]` if it's not numbers.  Can I get it to display in the traditional form without having to use `TraditionalForm`?

Comment: @MarkAdler Yes you can do that, too, but I wouldn't recommend it. To make the output behave differently, one would have to do something similar to what I did in [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/17989/245), but for `StandardForm`. It would require defining a wrapper function `myBinomial` so you don't have to modify the protected `Binomial` itself. Then the `Format` for that wrapper function can be defined to be what you want. I'll leave it up to you to adapt that other answer, since this question was only about input.

Comment: I'll look at that.  Thanks.  By the way, this question was also about the output.  You'd have to read the entire body of the question.  The title of the question is abbreviated and necessarily incomplete.

Comment: @MarkAdler Ah, I thought you'd be OK with a display that only works in `TraditionalForm`. I added something to make it work in `StandardForm`.

Comment: Awesome squared.  Works like a charm.  Thank you.

Comment: Nice. I suppose this can be modified to allow a user to enter Stirling numbers in Karamata's notation (i.e. $\left[n\atop k\right]$ for the cycle numbers, and $\left\{n\atop k\right\}$ for the subset numbers), right?

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. I think so - should I try to add that? I'll have time later today...

Comment: Only if it's convenient for you. :) It'd definitely be nice.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. I added your suggested notation for the Stirling numbers.

Comment: My only disappointment is that I cannot give you another upvote. This looks wonderful! :) (The cycle numbers are actually `(-1)^(n - k) StirlingS1[n, k]`, but that is a minor nit in an otherwise good answer.)