# A Box for the integral or partial derivative d

Tags: formatting, boxes

I am looking for the name of the box in the Box Language of Mma making integrals, such as those shown in the image below 
[image]
as well as of the sign of the partial derivative. I understand that I can get it through MakeBoxes trick, but it would be nicer to have special operator for such a purpose. The code with such an operator will be more concise.

Comment: You mean you want template boxes to appear after typing Esc pd ESC without pressing CTRL-_ ? This would also mean that you need a special key to extend the number of boxes for each differentiation variable, if needed, right? What exactly do you mean by `MakeBoxes` trick?

Comment: @Jens I hoped that there are special Box Language operators for the sign of integral, and that of the curved d (partial differential), just like there is one for Sqrt, the SqrtBox. My search revealed no of such. I use the Box language in rather complex constructs, where more simple methods work unsatisfactorily, while the Box Language works fine. There is a possibility to use the MakeBoxes operator, wrapping it around a usual expression. This I know how to do. I wanted to learn how to make the construct without this. You can see from my answer below that I found a workaround.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that there are no special boxes for these symbols. One can, however, use standard operators of the box language and insert there symbols from the palette Menu/Palettes/Special Characters/Symbols such as integral or partial derivativederivative. Like this one finds:

```
StyleBox[RowBox[{"\[Integral]", "y", "(", "x", ")", 
"\[DoubleStruckD]", "x"}], Italic] // DisplayForm
```

yielding

```
(*  \!\(
TagBox[
StyleBox[
RowBox[{"\[Integral]", "y", "(", "x", ")", "\[DoubleStruckD]", "x"}],
FontSlant->Italic],
DisplayForm]\)   *)
```

Otherwise, one can do this:

```
    StyleBox[RowBox[{"\[Integral]", "y(x)", "\[DoubleStruckD]x"}], 
  Italic] // DisplayForm
```

with the same effect. 
This, for instance,

```
    StyleBox[FractionBox["\[PartialD]y(x)", "\[PartialD]x"], 
  Italic] // DisplayForm
```

returns a partial derivative

Comment: One problem with these constructs is that they contain merely formatting and cannot be re-used as input if you copy them from the output cell. I thought you may be looking more for something along the lines of [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/45489/245),  where I made sure the interpretation of the formatted output is preserved. But I guess you're happy with the solution you found... there isn't anything really simpler I can think of.

Comment: @Jens Yes, Jens, my question has been related to a quite special case. Within a CDF paper I have buttons that open new windows with formulas. The buttons then work as references to the formulas. So I needed a sure enough way to put a formula inside a button. Problems arise sometimes, if it is opened on a machine with Mathematica. Then the formula that will open may interfere with variables Mathematica may know at that moment. The Box Language offers a sure way to avoid such a confusion.