# Kronecker delta notation

Tags: custom-notation

Is there an easier way to enter `KroneckerDelta[n,m]` in Mathematica?

When I use the notation $ \delta_{n,m} $, it won't work.

Comment: You can still define `delta[m_,n_]:=KroneckerDelta[m,n]` if you like :)

Comment: In version 9, with autocompletion enabled, only [3 letters are needed](http://i.stack.imgur.com/0R5GT.png).

Comment: You can enter the $\delta_{n,m}$ in a `TraditionalForm` equation cell, and then copy the equation into an input cell. That cell can then be evaluated if you allow *Mathematica* to interpret `TraditionalForm` input in the resulting dialog box. If you want more streamlined input, this is essentially the same as: [Can I enter the traditional form for Binomial as input in an expression?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/45488/245)

Comment: Would it be worthwhile to reformulate this question to something of the type, "What methods are available to simplify entering long function names in Mathematica"?  Having a single location for answers such as those posted in the comments might be beneficial to this community.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just

```
Subscript[\[Delta], m_, n_] := KroneckerDelta[n, m]
```

or am I missing something?

Comment: You might want to use `^:=` so that the rule gets attached to `\[Delta]` instead of `Subscript`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Notation` package.

```
<< Notation`
```

Use the `Notation` palette that automatically pops up to define the required notation.

```
Notation[Subscript[\[Delta], m_, n_] \[DoubleLongLeftRightArrow] KroneckerDelta[m_, n_]]
```

NOTE: This is only a "summary" of the required definition. You have to enter the full definition using the (first button on the) `Notation` palette, and then fill in the placeholders. You can enter the lefthand placeholder as $\delta_{m\_,n\_}$.

Now check that your input generates the intended `FullForm` expression. You can enter `Subscript[\[Delta], m, n]` as $\delta_{m,n}$.

```
Subscript[\[Delta], m, n] // FullForm

(* KroneckerDelta[m, n] *)
```