# Any hidden keyboard shortcut for RightTeeArrow?

Tags: keyboard

The Basic Math Assistant palette does not show a keyboard shortcut for RightTeeArrow.  Is there some hidden key combination that results in the output?  (Just hoping to be able to avoid having to reach for the mouse and move over.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to do purely typesetting, you could use the similar symbol for `Function`:

<kbd>Esc</kbd>fn<kbd>Esc</kbd>

> $\mapsto$

The *caveat* is that this symbol has a pre-defined meaning, as you can see by entering

```
TraditionalForm[Function[x,f[x]]]
```

> $x \mapsto f(x)$

If you enter the symbol only in equation cells that aren't meant to be evaluated, it doesn't matter that this pre-defined interpretation exists.

**Edit: making shortcuts, the user-friendly way**

If you want to be able to quickly make your own shortcuts for symbols or functions, it's also worth keeping in mind that there exists a package for that precise purpose: the [`Notation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/Notation/ref/Notation.html) package.

Although I personally also use the method in Mr. Wizard's answer [(see e.g. here)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/45489/245) to make shortcuts that are easy for others to copy (like on this site), still I would recommend looking into the `Notation` package for your own personal use (if you don't want to memorize the manual steps).

Just type this:

```
Needs["Notation`"]
```

<kbd>Esc</kbd>`addia`<kbd>Esc</kbd>

> `AddInputAlias["`$\square$ `" ->` $\square$`]`

This is the template that appears after typing the built-in shortcut. Now enter the desired abbreviation `rta` (or whatever you like) in the first square, and the character $\mapsto$ (`\[RightTeeArrow]`) in the second square.

And you're done.

Answer (score 8):

It is easy enough to add your own [`InputAliases`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/InputAliases.html).  For example evaluating:

```
CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], {InputAliases, "rta"}] = "↦";
```

Then entering <kbd>Esc</kbd>`rta`<kbd>Esc</kbd> will create a [`\[RightTeeArrow]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/character/RightTeeArrow.html) character.

To make the change global and persistent you can add this to the existing list using the [Option Inspector](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/OptionInspector.html) with the **Global Preferences** level selected.  (Advanced users can also do it programmatically but this is easier and less prone to error.)

---

In reply to a comment below there may be other character-related functionality you are unaware of.

#### Input Forms

Yes indeed you can enter characters using their *full name* ([`FullForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FullForm.html) representation), as well as several numeric forms as documented in [Input Syntax](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/InputSyntax.html).

- A list of the *full names* of characters is available in [Listing of Named Characters](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/ListingOfNamedCharacters.html).

The decimal character code is 8614:

```
ToCharacterCode["\[RightTeeArrow]"]
```

> ```
> {8614}
> ```

This in hexadecimal is `21a6` therefore you can also enter the character as `\:21a6`.

#### Operator Behavior

Since `↦` is an [Operator](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/Operators.html) it also has established parsing behavior and translation rules to and from the attached Symbol name: [`RightTeeArrrow`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RightTeeArrrow.html). Examples:

[image]
[image]

This allows you to easily define rules for the operator (following said parsing behavior):

```
RightTeeArrow[a_, b_] := a + b
RightTeeArrow[a_, b_, c_] := a*b*c
RightTeeArrow[x__] := {x}
```

Now:

[image]

#### Extensible Characters

`\[RightTeeArrow]` is an *extensible character*.  If you create an overscript using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd> as described in the [Control Keys](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/InputSyntax.html#18584) section of the Input Syntax tutorial and enter it above an expression it stretches to fit:

[image]

Comment: Excellent advice.  Moreover, I didn't know that you could use the "long form" `\[RightTeeArrow]` for these kinds of things.

Comment: @Shredderroy Please see my updated answer.

Comment: I recommend using `CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], {InputAliases, "rta"}] = "\[RightTeeArrow]"` instead, since this will not delete existing input aliases.

Comment: @Carl Excellent suggestion, as usual.  I'll amend the post.