# Add keyboard shortcut without creating a new menu item

Tags: front-end, keyboard

I want to some key combination like CtrlShift+ to insert Print[ ]; into a workbook.  I used

```
 FrontEndExecute[FrontEnd`AddMenuCommands[
 "DuplicatePreviousOutput", {Delimiter, MenuItem["Print[ ];",
 FrontEnd`KernelExecute[nb = SelectedNotebook[];
 NotebookWrite[nb, Cell[BoxData[RowBox[{"Print[ ];"}]], "Input"]];], 
 MenuKey["+", Modifiers -> {"Control", {"Shift"}}], 
 System`MenuEvaluator -> Automatic]}]]
```

[from this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16165/how-can-i-set-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-run-a-command). It works nicely, but it adds a new item to the insert menu every time I use it.  I've tried as many ways as I can think of to simplify the code, but it never works after these changes. I would rather not use the Esc string Esc approach discussed here [Escape](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/47247/any-hidden-keyboard-shortcut-for-rightteearrow) because it requires several keystrokes.

Comment: So you want to easily replace functionality for a shortcut? If so, the `joker` functionality from `Shortcuts` package should fit your need. Take a look on example: [34159](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/34159/5478). Is this what you need?

Comment: @Kuba - Yes it works.  It nice to also have those other shortcuts. Thanks.

Comment: Great :) let's mark it as a duplicate then :)