# How can I stop Mathematica from re-arranging formulae in TraditionalForm?

Tags: formatting

Let's say I have a sample formula, for example `(Abs[x]/(-(2 - \[Kappa]) - 5))/(Binomial[a, b]/4)` or something like that. I can of course typeset it *to a limited degree and with not necessarily nice results*:

[image]

It is so small that this x is barely distinguishable from this kappa, and I can't typeset `Abs` or `Binomial`.

So I use `TraditionalForm` and I get this:

[image]

This is certainly much nicer. But my formula got rearranged heavily. Yes, I have to admit it, it looks much prettier this way *in that particular case* (sometimes TraditionalForm actually makes formulae less clear), but this is not what I wanted to achieve. I wanted my formula to be displayed in LaTeX quality **exactly as I typed it**!

So I add a `HoldForm` just to get this:

[image]

Phew. And they call THIS a "held form".

I can get what I want if I also enter a `HoldForm` in the middle of the formula in the right place:

[image]

But in more complex examples I have to spam those `HoldForms` obnoxiously, which is annoying. Also having `HoldForms` in the middle of formulae can get annoying, since this will affect evaluation.

How to stop this rearranging? Isn't there anything like, say, `TraditionalForm[StopRearranging[formula]]`?

Comment: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/RepresentingTextualFormsByBoxes.html  and http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/LowLevelNotebookStructure.html may be helpful.

Comment: Are you typing your formulas in an `input` cell? None of this would happen if you were using one of the cell styles that are meant for that purpose, like `DisplayFormula`. So you should perhaps clarify what you really want to do with the typed formulas eventually: i.e., use them only for display or do other calculations with them.

Comment: You might want to apply TraditionalForm at single parts of your formula. Highlight `Abs[x]` and use CTRL+SHIFT+T, then highlight `Binomial[a,b]` and do the same. Highlight the whole formula and type CTRL+B to remove the bold style. Is this what you are after? (This will work if you use TraditionalForm as default Input method, otherwise you'll have to use Cell Display As... Traditional Form to convert it without touching it).

Comment: @Jens Checked this. Typed the formula in a `DisplayFormula` cell. Right-clicked and selected `Convert to` -> `TraditionalForm`. The formula still got re-arranged.

Comment: The point is that the `DisplayFormula` Cell is *already* in `TraditionalForm`. You don't need to convert anything.

Comment: @Jens So how can I, for example, typeset `Abs[x]`?

Comment: Sorry - I wrote an answer to clarify what I meant... I first needed to be sure what your goal was, so my comment was a bit short.

Answer (score 5):

### Addendum

It's worth examining how your original expression was rendered in `TraditionalForm`, even though it was not just what you wanted.

```
exp = (Abs[x]/(-(2 - \[Kappa]) - 5))/(Binomial[a, b]/4) // TraditionalForm
```

[image: add1]

Let's look at the underlying structure:

```
tagExp = ToBoxes[exp]
```

> TagBox[FormBox[
>     FractionBox[RowBox[{"4", " ", TemplateBox[{"x"}, "Abs"]}], 
>      RowBox[{RowBox[{"(", RowBox[{"[Kappa]", "-", "7"}], ")"}], " ", 
>        TemplateBox[{"a", "b"}, "Binomial"]}]], 
>   TraditionalForm], TraditionalForm, Editable -> True]

Let's invert the process to check whether this code will result in the rendering we began with:

```
tagExp//DisplayForm
```

[image: add1]

And now we get a treeform display of the structure:

```
tagExp // TreeForm
```

[image: tree]

You may be able to tweak the `TagBox` coding to obtain what you are looking for.

---

Here's a somewhat simpler, seat-of-the-pants approach.
I'm not sure this is an improvement on what you came up with.  But, here goes.

For this `FractionBox` seems to be the place to start.  But in other circumstances other formatting boxes (`StyleBox, SuperscriptBox, SubscriptBox`, etc.) may be required.

---

The general structure of your problem is

```
FractionBox["top", "bottom"] // DisplayForm
```

[image: structure]

Once you realize this, you can move ahead to deal with the top and bottom (or numerator and denominator, if you prefer).

Yes, you might have formatted this as a simple fraction using `/`. But this is a live operator that could give you trouble as you move forward.  `FractionBox` is your outermost frame, so to speak.

---

Let' s begin with the bottom, since that seems more straightforward.

```
bottom = Binomial[a, b]/4 // TraditionalForm
```

[image: frac1]

---

Let's put the bottom into the `FractionBox` structure:

```
FractionBox["top", bottom] // DisplayForm
```

[image: struc2]

---

The top itself can be put into its own `FractionBox`.  Like you, I had to use `HoldForm` to accomplish this.

```
top = FractionBox[Abs[x] // TraditionalForm, HoldForm[(-(2 - \[Kappa]) - 5)]] // DisplayForm
```

[image: struc3]

---

Let's now insert the top into the outermost `FractionBox`

```
FractionBox[top, bottom] // DisplayForm
```

[image: out1]

---

If that's too small, wrap it in `Style`:

```
Style[FractionBox[top, bottom], 24] // DisplayForm
```

[image: out2]

`StyleBox` will produce the same effect.  And it may actually be more appropriate here.

```
StyleBox[FractionBox[top, bottom], 24] // DisplayForm
```

Answer (score 3):

Firstly to address the start of the question in which you didn't like how small everything was. This can be fixed quite simply by changing an option to `FractionBox`

```
FractionBoxOptions -> {AllowScriptLevelChange -> False}
```

Normally you would set this as part of a style sheet for `Input` style or you could set it at the cell level using the options inspector. To see it in use I am setting it for the entire notebook as per the animated gif below:

[image]

For the second part of your question, to stop your reordering you can wrap stuff in `PolynomialForm` and set the option `TraditionalOrder` to `False`. You can still use `TraditionalForm` so that you get traditional typesetting of the binomial but the problem with this approach is that it only stops reordering of the final rearranged expression. You need to intervene before the fractions boxes get rearranged ...which is what you have discovered by using `HoldForm`.

```
TraditionalForm@
 PolynomialForm[(Abs[x]/(-(2 - \[Kappa]) - 5))/(Binomial[a, b]/4), 
  TraditionalOrder -> False]
```

[image]

Notwithstanding that there are styles that facilitate this type of typesetting, if you want to do it in an `Input` cell then just highlight the bits that you want to look traditional and convert those.

[image]

Note that syntax styling is switched off for traditional form (which is why `x`, `a`, and `b` are not pink) but you can set it on via the options settings.

Answer (score 1):

From the comments I infer that you are indeed interested only in typesetting formulas and displaying the in `TraditionalForm`. If you enter the equation in an **inline cell**, it will be in `TraditionalForm`. On the other hand, `DisplayFormula` cells need to be converted to `TraditionalForm` **before** you start typing (assuming that you work with the default stylesheet).

Once you are in a cell that displays in `TraditionalForm`, the issue is how to enter things like `Abs[x]` and `Binomial[a,b]` so that they display properly. This is indeed not as convenient as it should be (compared to $\LaTeX$). Specifically  for the binomial, I had posted a solution in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/45489/245).

For the `Abs` function, you could simply use the `Basic Math` palette.