# How do you put conditions on indices in a sum?

Tags: summation

I'm relatively inexperienced with mathematica, so I apologize if this is a trivial question. I want to take a double sum over a function $f(i,j)$ of two indices, of the form
$$
\sum_{i = -\infty}^\infty \sum_{j = 0\atop j\not = i}^m f(i,j).
$$
That is, in the inner sum I want to sum over only those indices $j$ in my range of summation that satisfy the assumption $j \not = i$. How can I input such a sum to Mathematica?

Comment: Use `Boole[]` or `KroneckerDelta[]`. See [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9288) as well.

Comment: Change function inside sum to: `Sign[Abs[i - j]] f[i,j]`, not very elegant but it works.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use `Boole` as follows:

```
Sum[f[i, j] Boole[i != j], {j, 0, m}, {i, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

Here's an example where `f[i, j] = Sin[i] Cos[j]`

```
Sum[Sin[i] Cos[j] Boole[i != j], {j, 0, 3}, {i, 0, 3}]
```

Which gives

```
Sin[1] + Cos[2] Sin[1] + Cos[3] Sin[1] + Sin[2] + Cos[1] Sin[2] + 
 Cos[3] Sin[2] + Sin[3] + Cos[1] Sin[3] + Cos[2] Sin[3]
```

Comment: @NickStrehlke, glad I could help.

Comment: What if f[i,j] diverges when i=j? Imagine f[i,j]=M[i,j]^(-a), where M[i,j] is a matrix with M[i,j]=0 if i=j, and a is a positive integer number. @RunnyKine

Comment: @RunnyKine Do you know how to do double summation with conditions.     https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/250873/double-summation-with-condition

Answer (score 25):

You can use `If` to put the condition in the argument of the sum. It would be something like

```
Sum[If[i != j, f[i, j], 0], {i, -Infinity, Infinity}, {j, 0, m}]
```

where `If[i != j, f[i,j], 0]` tells Mathematica to use $f(i,j)$ in the sum if $i\neq{j}$ or 0 if $i=j$.

Comment: Thank you! This answer was helpful too.

Comment: I found that your If solution works better than the Boole by RunnyKine, because it allows f[i,j] to be undefined at i == j.