# Skip certain values in a sum

Tags: summation

How can I evaluate such a sum:

$$
\sum_{j=0, j\neq10}^{J} f(j)
$$

Since I am trying to do some symbolic calculations, solutions such as the one below are undesirable:

$$
-f(10) + \sum_{j=0}^{J} f(j)
$$

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can start by creating a list of all the values you want to iterate through:

```
indices = DeleteCases[Range[0,J],10];
```

And then do either

```
Sum[f[i], {i, indices}]
```

or

```
Total[f /@ indices]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use an `If` statement:

```
Sum[If[i == 10, 0, f[i]], {i, J}]
```

Comment: It's probably equivalent but I find this syntax more elegant: `Sum[f[j] Boole[j != 10], {j, 0, J}]`

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways basically.
First one:

```
Sum[f(j)*Boole[j != 10], {j, 0, 10}]
```

Another way is:

```
Sum[If[j != 10, Sin[1] Cos[j], 0], {j, 0, 10}]
```

See this link too: [How do you put conditions on indices in a sum?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25882/how-do-you-put-conditions-on-indices-in-a-sum)

Answer (score 0):

The solutions given above are correct, and probably the best way to go.

But if you can be absolutely certain that `f(10)` is not an expensive call, it might even be better to do something like what you are saying, since it would avoid having to making a comparison for each index `i`.

So you could do the following:

```
g[x_] := f[x];
g[10] := 0;
Total[g /@ Range[100000]]
```