# Conditions on a product

Tags: conditional, products

I want to impose specific conditions on a product I am trying to take. I found [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25882/how-do-you-put-conditions-on-indices-in-a-sum) previous question asked here but when I use this I get zero. My expression is 
$$
\prod_{(i,j)=(-a+1,-b+1)}^{(a,b)}\frac{1}{ix+jy}
$$
with the condition that $(i,j) \neq \{(0,0),(a,b) \}$. How could I ask Mathematica to calculate this for me (e.g. for some specific values of $a,b$)?

Comment: You don't have `i,j` dependence in the term, would this expression simply equals to (1/(a x+b y))^(2a+2b-4)?

Comment: Sorry, typo! Fixing it now!!!!

Comment: You can use `If[]` or `Piecewise[]` within `Product[]`.

Answer (score 2):

You can define a function to take care the special case. For example:

```
f[0, 0] = 1;
f[i_, j_] := 1/(i x + j y)

With[{a = 2, b = 2}, Product[f[i, j], {i, -a + 1, a - 1}, {j, -b + 1, b - 1}]]
(* 1/(x^2 (-x - y) (x - y) y^2 (-x + y) (x + y)) *)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. Ok, that takes care one of the conditions so I can do the same for the other I guess. By the way, I did not know such a thing is possible.

Comment: Since the other conditions are at the end points so they can be excluded by setting the range to from `-a+1` to `a-1` and from `-b+1` to `b-1`.

Comment: Yes, but then I am not sure if the case $a=1,b=1$ makes sense. If I use what you write then I get $1/(xy)$ while I should have an empty product since both $a,b$ cannot take the values $0,1$.

Comment: I get 1 instead of 1/(x+y).

Comment: Without changing the "boundaries". I.e. I do not want to demand that the product stops at $a-1,b-1$ because in the formula I see (and I do not understand why) it is explicitly written as the product up to $a,b$ although the values $a,b$ are excluded. Basically, I will make a slight alteration to the product in my question so you see what I exactly have. Now, the product is properly written.

Comment: I don't see why that's necessary but if you don't want to change the boundary then you can do the same thing for the other boundary, by defining the special cases.

Answer (score 1):

```
pF = Product[If[MatchQ[{i, j}, {0, 0} | {#2, #3}], 1, #],
            {i, -#2 + 1, #2}, {j, -#3 + 1, #3}] &;

pF[1/(i x + j y), 1, 1]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

```
pF[1/(i x + j y), 2, 2]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

```
pF[1/(i x + j y), 3, 2]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]