# Infinite Sum with exclusion

Tags: summation

From another [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9288/sum-or-product-with-exclusions) I tried to implement something like:

```
Sum[r^(1 - l[n]) DD[n], {n, Complement[Range[1, Infinity], {4}]}]
```

but this does not work because Range does not take infinite limits.

Is there another way to exclude a certain numeric value for the index from an infinite sum?

Comment: Sum[r^(1 - l[n]) DD[n], {n, 1, 3}] +
 Sum[r^(1 - l[n]) DD[n], {n, 5, Infinity}]

Comment: Well, this is not very practical if I have many excluded values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you know your exclusions beforehand, you can proceed like this (for any number of exclusions!):

```
excl={4,9,14}; (* just an example of more than one exclusion! *)
Sum[r^(1-l[n]) DD[n],{n, Select[Range[1, Max@excl],!MemberQ[excl,#]&]}]+
  Sum[r^(1-l[n]) DD[n],{n,Max@excl+1,Infinity}]
```

This will filter out *all* your exclusions in one run.

It will also deal with exclusions you make to avoid the summed expression to become invalid at those points.

Answer (score 3):

An straightforward way to put exclusions into sums is by using [`KroneckerDelta`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/KroneckerDelta.html):

```
excl = {4, 9, 14};
Sum[
  Times @@ (1 - Thread[KroneckerDelta[n, excl]]) r^(1 - l[n]) DD[n], 
 {n, 1, Infinity}
]
```

> $$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \text{DD}(n)
>    (1-\delta _{4,n}) (1-\delta
>    _{9,n}) (1-\delta _{14,n})
>    r^{1-l(n)}$$

To show that this also works when the summand would otherwise be undefined, here is an example:

```
DD[n_] := 1/(n - 9)^2

Sum[
 Times @@ (1 - Thread[KroneckerDelta[n, excl]])  DD[n], {n, 1, 
  Infinity}]

(* ==> (1021301 + 117600 Pi^2)/705600 *)
```

So the divergent term never gets evaluated because the `KroneckerDelta` sets it to zero first.

Comment: Nice! One drawback, though: It does not deal with the case, that exclusions are made because of the summed expression is not defined at those points.

Comment: @Jinxed Actually, it does. I'll give an example in my answer.